# When using an ASP.Net UpdatePanel, requests from Popup window are blocked

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-ajax, updatepanel

All,

I have an UpdatePanel that is making a couple of long-running request to gather a lot of data. Sometimes it takes up to 90 sec to return.

The first request returns data that is rendered as a link to a document.  Clicking the link opens a new browser window and the URL has a query string that tells the system which doc to open.

Here is a snip of code when rendering the link for the client:

```
 HtmlAnchor alink = new HtmlAnchor();
 alink.HRef = "javascript:openDocument('"+ item.Url +"')";   //item.Url;

// here is the JS on the client page
function openDocument(path) {
    window.open(path);
 }
```

So, when the user clicks the link, the popup window does open. The problem is that it waits until the UpdatePanel is complete with its request before the popup window sends its request.

I can copy the url from the popup, open a new browser and then paste the URL into the new browser and it opens the doc as expected.

This leads me to believe that the UpdatePanel is somehow blocking the popup window's request.  I'd rather not make the user wait until the UpdatePanel's AJAX request has completed before the user can open docs from the first result.

How can I work around this blockage?  I've tried creating buttons outside of the ContentArea of the UpdatePanel and simulating clicks, but nothing like that works either.

Does anyone have an idea about this?

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: How are the requests made? By postbacks? Have you tried implementing javascript code directly to the aspx-file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is that the pages are using Session state so any request blocks all other that share the same session key.

If your page does not write to the session then you can apply [IReadOnlySessionState](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.sessionstate.ireadonlysessionstate.aspx) attribute to them so that they only block if there is a non-readonly request and not if all concurrent requests are using read-only Session.

```
public class YourPage: Page, IReadOnlySessionState { ... }
```